# Display issue with Adobe Digital Editions on Windows 11 with Iris graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, windows-11

I have just got a new laptop (an LG Gram) with an 11th gen i5 using the Iris integrated GPU and Windows 11. When I try to read an epub book with Adobe Digital Editions 4.5 and 2.0 (both versions show the same problem) the page does not refresh when I move to the next page. That is, the book opens fine and displays the last page read, but when I press PgDn or click the "next page" icon the text doesn't change.

This is some sort of refresh problem because if I resize the window, or press ctrl-T to show/hide the navigation panel, the display immediately updates to show the current page.

I've tried this on another laptop with an 8th gen i5 running Windows 11 and Digital Editions works fine on that laptop. This suggests it isn't a Windows 11 compatibility problem, so I wonder if it's the Iris graphics in the 11th gen CPU. Unfortunately I don't have an 11th gen laptop running Windows 10 to check.

I have tried different compatibility settings for the DE executable, but found no difference. I've Googled for info on this issue without any luck.

So my question is has anyone else encountered the problem and can anyone suggest a fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this [on the Intel support forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Adobe-Digital-Editions-problem-using-Iris-graphics/m-p/1365914#M106062) and it was a bug in the Iris drivers that ship with Windows 11. It is fixed by the 30.0.101.1340 version of the drivers, [which are available here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-dch-drivers.html).